# Apache NiFi ReplaceText

Tags: java, regex, etl, apache-nifi

Am trying to replace a pipe | with a new line using ReplaceText processor but instead am getting everything put on a new line instead of just everything after the pipe

Comment: It will be great if you could share the code you are using for this

Answer (score 0):

Just set '|' in SearchValue
Than open ReplaceValue and pres Shift+Enter in Edit box.
And change Replacment Strategy to Literal replacment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `\|` on the SearchValue and then on the ReplaceValue I used Shift+Enter in the edit box.